# CMake on MSYS2 freezes up

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, msys

I'm running MSYS2 on Windows 8, and having problems with CMake freezing / locking up.

Here's a minimal example:

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{   
   std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project (helloworld)
add_executable(helloworld main.cpp)
```

If I open the MSYS2 console, go to the directory in which both of the above files are located, and execute the command

```
cmake .
```

there is no further output and the console locks up. An empty CMakeFiles folder is created, but nothing else happens. I've tried with CMake 3.10.2 and 3.2.3 and the same happens for both versions.

---

Below is some `strace`output if at all of interest:
If I run the command

```
strace cmake .
```

I get different output at different times. Sometimes the final line is something like

```
19   4436   [main] cmake 2320 child_copy: done
```

Sometimes it is something like

```
44   239509 [main] cmake 9820 open_shared: name cygpid.10668 n 10668, shared 0xBB0000 (wanted 0x0), h 0x344, *m 6
```

And sometimes the end of the output is something like

```
   20 2735480 [main] cmake 14200 kill_pgrp: killing pid 5900, pgrp 5900, p->ctty /dev/pty0, ctty /dev/pty5
   24 2735504 [main] cmake 14200 sig_send: 1 = SetNamedPipeHandleState (0x358, PIPE_NOWAIT, NULL, NULL)
   16 2735520 [main] cmake 14200 sig_send: sendsig 0x358, pid 5900, signal 17, its_me 0
   19 2735539 [main] cmake 14200 sig_send: Not waiting for sigcomplete.  its_me 0 signal 17
   24 2735563 [main] cmake 14200 sig_send: returning 0x0 from sending signal 17
   23 2735586 [main] cmake 14200 _pinfo::kill: 0 = _pinfo::kill (17), pid 5900, process_state 0x4C5
   20 2735606 [main] cmake 14200 kill_pgrp: killing pid 15152, pgrp 15152, p->ctty /dev/pty5, ctty /dev/pty5
 3486 2739092 [main] cmake 14200 sig_send: 1 = SetNamedPipeHandleState (0x3A0, PIPE_NOWAIT, NULL, NULL)
   44 2739136 [main] cmake 14200 sig_send: sendsig 0x3A0, pid 15152, signal 17, its_me 0
   33 2739169 [main] cmake 14200 sig_send: Not waiting for sigcomplete.  its_me 0 signal 17
   27 2739196 [main] cmake 14200 sig_send: returning 0x0 from sending signal 17
   25 2739221 [main] cmake 14200 _pinfo::kill: 0 = _pinfo::kill (17), pid 15152, process_state 0x61
```

What could be the reason for these problems?

---

EDIT:
The output of

```
cmake . --trace
```

is as follows, before it freezes:

```
Running with trace output on.
d/Dropbox/Programming/Cplusplus/workspace/Testprograms/test_cmake/CMakeLists.txt(1): cmakeminimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0 )
d/Dropbox/Programming/Cplusplus/workspace/Testprograms/test_cmake/CMakeLists.txt(2): project(helloworld ) 
usr/share/cmake-3.10.2/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake(36): 
if(CMAKE_HOST_UNIX )
usr/share/cmake-3.10.2/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake(37): find_program(CMAKE_UNAME uname /bin /usr/bin /usr/local/bin ) 
usr/share/cmake-3.10.2/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake(38): if(CMAKE_UNAME)
usr/share/cmake-3.10.2/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake(39): if(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL AIX )
usr/share/cmake-3.10.2/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake(45): else() 
usr/share/cmake-3.10.2/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake(46): 
exec_program(${CMAKE_UNAME1 ARGS -r OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION )
```

Comment: What about `cmake --trace` instead of `strace cmake`? Does it still hang?

Comment: Also, have you tried uninstalling the MSYS2 package and installing the Windows native CMake instead? I realize it's a pain to type the MSYS2 equivalent of `$(cygpath -w /cygdrive/c/path/to/directory/)` to feed the Windows version of CMake the directory `C:\path\to\directory`, but this is only for testing; [MSYS2 adds some patches to CMake](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/tree/master/cmake) prior to its build that may be the problem.

Comment: Lastly, ensure your environment is updated: `pacman -Syuu`. If it is, you might search for an existing issue or open a new one on the [MSYS2 packages issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/alexpux/msys2-packages/issues) for CMake. While perhaps unrelated since MSYS2 and MINGW are fairly different (like MINGW and Cygwin), I did find [this issue](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/issues/2062) in the MINGW packages issue tracker. Perhaps something similar is happening to what's described there and killing cc1.exe works? It might be something to include in your own bug report.

Comment: And if you've upgraded recently, you might consider downgrading something that was recently upgraded.

Comment: I added the output of `cmake --trace` as an edit (yes, it still hangs).

If I explicitly call Windows' CMake installation, `/f/ProgramFiles/CMake/bin/cmake.exe .. -G "Unix Makefiles"
` it works! I'll file a bug report. Thanks for the help!

Comment: is there any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

CMake doesn't like in tree builds. Make a separate build folder.

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

CMake doesn't build your programs, it only creates build files.  Your next step would be.

```
mingw32-make
```

Unless you have other issues, you should be able to run your program.

Mike

Comment: That doesn't work either. This time I got the error message `4 [main] cmake 16324 chi1d_info_fork::abort: F:\msy532\usr\bin\msys—idn2—O.d11: Loaded to different address: parent(0x370000) != chi1d(0x800000)`

Comment: 1- Is that the only error? 2- Are you running MinGW or Cygwin? 3- At what stage are you getting this error?

Comment: Re 2-: it's MSYS2, a fork of Cygwin using Arch Linux's `pacman` and `makepkg` packaging system, and probably a lot of other customizations.